# Adding overlay to body except an element

Tags: javascript, jquery

**CSS**

```
.myoverlay
        {
            position: absolute;
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7); 
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            right: 0;
            opacity: 0.5;
        }
```

**HTML**

```
   <html>
    <head></head>


    <body>    

    <div id="MyDiv">
    //some content
    </div>

    </body>


    </html>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function(){

 $("body").not('#MyDiv').addClass("myoverlay");


});
```

Here I want to apply the overlay to the body except MyDiv. The code above shown is applying the overlay for complete body including MyDiv.

Comment: I think a better solution would be to get the position of the `div` and position it absolute above the body. Then you can apply the overlay class to the body (or to a special overlay element) and just keep the div you want to highlight above it.

Comment: If also you add a placeholder element where the original element used to be, then you also preserve the layout. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/3fzLA/ (note that the button is still visible below the blue box).

Comment: Which `div`? Which browser are you using?

Comment: I meant the foo and bar divs. I'm using MOzilla.

Comment: It works fine for me, in Chrome and Firefox. The blue div is above the overlay.

Answer (score 1):

Here is code! Is it what you want?

```
<html>
            <head>
                <title></title>
                <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
                <style>
                    .myoverlay:not(#MyDiv) {
                        position: absolute;
                        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
                        top: 0;
                        left: 0;
                        bottom: 0;
                        right: 0;
                        opacity: 0.5;

                    }
                    #MyDiv {
                        width: 200px;
                        height: 200px;
                        background: White;
                        z-index: 10;
                    }
                </style>
            </head>
            <body>
                <div class="wrapper">
                    <div id="MyDiv">
                        <div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </body>
            <script>
                $(function () {
                    $('.wrapper').addClass('myoverlay');
                });
            </script>
        </html>
```

Comment: Please explain why your solution solves the problem. Posting code only is generally not very helpful.

Comment: Ok. Instead of add class .myoverlay in body tag, I added it in div with class named wrapper. And the class .myoverlay I just modified like  .myoverlay:not(#MyDiv). And the jquery code I wrote $('.wrapper').addClass('myoverlay');

Answer (score 0):

you can using only css by adding div that have overlay and exclude the part that you want from it

```css
.overlay:not(.exclude){
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  padding-top:2em;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}

.exclude {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 100;
  padding: 15px !important;
  margin-left: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div style="padding:20px" class="overlay">

  <h2>Overlay</h2>
  <p>Add an overlay effect to the page content </p>
  
  <button  class="exclude">Turn on overlay effect</button>
</div>
```